# Continuity of a function defined by an integral 2

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, continuity

suppose that $h(x,y)$ is an integrable function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and continuous in $x=x_0$. Is the function
$$g(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}h(x,y)dy$$ continuous in $x=x_0$?

In fact, my problem is related to conditional densities and expectations: if $f(y|X=x)\geq 0$ is the conditional density function of the random variables $(x,y)$ with support in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and continuous in $x=x_0$, is it correct to say that the conditional expectation
$$E(y|X=x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}yf(y|X=x)dy$$ is also continuous in $x=x_0$? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Consider $h(x, y) = x(1-|y/x|)$ for $0<x<1$ and $h(x,y)=0$ otherwise with $x_0=0$.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't quite understand your example

Comment: that $h$ satisfies your assumptions. Now, compute $g(x)$ for $x=0$ and $x\in (0, 1)$. Btw. $h$ is a pdf.